# Spring OAuth2RestTemplate closing response prior to HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData() call

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Within the doExecute() of the RestTemplate class there is the following code:

```
        ...
        response = request.execute();
        if (!getErrorHandler().hasError(response)) {
            logResponseStatus(method, url, response);
        }
        else {
            handleResponseError(method, url, response);
        }
        if (responseExtractor != null) {
            return responseExtractor.extractData(response);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
        ...
```

When using the OAuth2RestTemplate the ResponseErrorHandler is set to the OAuth2ErrorHandler. In my specific use case the request (after getting an oauth token) is returning a 400 error that I want to handle within my code. As such I have created the OAuth2ErrorHandler by passing in my custom handler that overrides the DefaultResponseHandler.handleError() to do nothing. This will allow the code calling the RestTemplate.postForEntity() to get back the ResponseEntity so that I can do further evaluation against it.

Now the problem I am seeing is that within the handleResponseError, in the code above, it goes into the OAuth2ErrorHandler.handleError() and within that code there is a note about:

```
        ...
        // Need to use buffered response because input stream may need to be consumed multiple times.
        ClientHttpResponse bufferedResponse = new ClientHttpResponse() {
        ...
```

This works well when the OAuth2ErrorHandler calls the delegate errorHandler as that errorHandler can then read the response as well. Unfortunately when that method returns the bufferedResponse is no longer available and when the responseExtractor.extractData(response) is called the input stream has been closed.

Here is the exception that I am seeing:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Attempted read from closed stream.; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:788)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:773)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:553)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:506)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:361)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:137)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.ensureLoaded(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:503)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.detectEncoding(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.constructParser(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:224)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory._createParser(JsonFactory.java:1242)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:753)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2158)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Is there a way to work around this issue? For my use case I would like to continue using the OAuth2RestTemplate to handle my OAuth handshake as well as being able to have my own code logic run against the ResponseEntity.

Comment: I think that's just a long way of saying you can't process a 400 response in an `OAuth2RestTemplate`? That would be bad. Maybe it could rephrase the question and describe in more detail how you at up the rest template and where the 400 comes from?

Comment: My specific use case was using the OAuth2RestTemplate to connect to Amazon Device Messaging API. This API requires an oauth token before sending a message to a device. The API has a state of returning a 400 level response when a registration id is invalid or the request body is missing specific information. When that 400 response is received I get the above errors that I stated originally.

Comment: Can you open a ticket in github about custom error handlers in `OAuth2RestTemplate`?

Comment: @DaveSyer Did find any workaround for this ??

Comment: I wasn't looking for a workaround, but I'm sure you can do something with `OAuth2RestTemplate` and an `AccessTokenProvider`.